# feed url problem

Tags: code, videos, youtube

hey hii everyone,
i have a function to fetch the videos from the rss feed of youtube, so that i can display selected videos to my blog
for that i am using this youtube-search-feed url
`http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/videos?q=eminem&client=ytapi-youtube-search&v=2`

in the url, eminem is included, so it will display me videos of eminem,
now my problem is, instead of eminem it should take my posts title name, so if i write this code

`$rss = fetch_rss('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/videos?q='.the_title().'&client=ytapi-youtube-search&v=2');`

then its returning me with a false video

here is my entire code

```
    <?php 
$newvar = str_replace(' ', '', the_title());
include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/rss.php');
$rss = fetch_rss('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/videos?q='.$newvar.'&client=ytapi-youtube-search&v=2');
    $maxitems = 1; 
    $items = array_slice($rss->items, 0, $maxitems);
                            ?>
```

here i am using `$newvar` to strip the spaces in between of the title of the posts
**@rarst** i change the code but now i am not getting the video

here is the code

```
<?php 
$newvar = str_replace(' ', '', the_title());
include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php');
$feed = fetch_feed('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/videos?q='.$newvar.'&client=ytapi-youtube-search&v=2');
$maxitems = 1; 
$items = array_slice($feed->items, 0, $maxitems);
?>
```

Comment: Could you please add actual title(s) example? Also `fetch_rss()` is very outdated and deprecated, please use [`fetch_feed()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed).

Comment: I would use `urlencode()` around the title, so you never have problems with special characters in the title. This way you don't have to remove spaces.

Comment: i added the `fetch_feed()` but now i am getting no videos
check my og answer for current edited code

Comment: Using `urlencode` as @Jan Fabry pointed out will give you better results, but you should get search results either way. Can you show us the code that displays the results? Or try `var_dump($items)` to see what format the results are in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if this is your only issue, but you're using `the_title()` to build your URI. This ECHOS the title, which is not what you want.

Instead, you should be using [get_the_title()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title).

I'd also urlencode the title, as Jan suggested.

Your best bet is to print out the YouTube URI after you build it, then try to hit it in a browser. If the results aren't right, the problem is with your URI.

Comment: ok I used `get_the_title()` and it worked for me, but now the problem is when the title has two words then i have to remove spaces between them, but i tried `str_replace` and `urlencode` but it doesn't works,
how can i remove spaces between the title?

Comment: hey made it, now the videos are coming, but just last thing i am still using `fetch_rss` function will there be any problem with this in future?

Comment: Yes--fetch_rss() is deprecated, meaning it may be removed from future versions of Wordpress. You should switch to using fetch_feed. But note that they have slightly different usage, and you'll need to update your code--you can't just change the function name. Read the docs on fetch_feed (as Rarst suggested) for more info.